# Why did House Atreides have to give up Caladan, while the Harkonnens were allowed to stay on Geidi Prime while also controlling Arrakis?

Tags: dune

In the first Dune book, we see House Atreides pack up and move permanently to Arrakis, even though they clearly have deep ties to Caladan. We also learn that the Harkonnens were allowed to maintain Geidi Prime as their homeworld, even as they had full control of Arrakis. Why couldn't Leto stay on Caladan with Jessica and Paul, and send Duncan or Gurney to govern Arrakis, the way Raban was doing so on behalf of the Baron?

Comment: Caladan was home to Shaddam IV’s favorite sushi place. Besides who really wants Geidi Prime besides a Harkonnen?

Comment: Other than that it was a trap intended to wipe out House Atreides?

Comment: But what was the legal rule and precedent used by Shaddam IV when granting Arrakis on different terms to the Harkonnensand to the Atreides?

Comment: @M.A.Golding The actual question is did there need to be one other than ‘the Emperor ordered it’?  While Leto did assume it was a trap, most lords would probably consider losing their old world as the price for Dune to be worth it.

Comment: Strongly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251164/21267

Comment: @suchiuomizu The answer to that question obviously is "yes". Otherwise, he could have just, like, ordered Leto to commit seppuku or something. The plot of Dune is fundamentally dependent on the emperor having not much more power than being the head of the most prominent house among many.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Harkonnen were simply under *contract to supervise the mining of the spice on Arrakis* whereas the Atreides family were given the planet entire, *including the responsibility for mining the spice*.

Since the rules seem to be that you can only have one planet as your fiefdom, this meant that they had to give up Caladan.

> Thufir Hawat, his father’s Master of Assassins, had explained it:
> their mortal enemies, the Harkonnens, had been on Arrakis eighty
> years, **holding the planet in quasi-fief under a CHOAM Company
> contract to mine the geriatric spice**, melange. **Now the Harkonnens were
> leaving to be replaced by the House of Atreides in fief-complete** — an
> apparent victory for the Duke Leto. Yet, Hawat had said, this
> appearance contained the deadliest peril, for the Duke Leto was
> popular among the Great Houses of the Landsraad.

Note that the Baron's plan was not to gain the fiefdom of the planet (since no House Major can have more than one planet) but to gain a sub-fiefdom, independent control in all but name.

> Piter shrugged. “If matters go as planned,” he said, “House Harkonnen
> will have a subfief on Arrakis within a Standard year. Your uncle will
> have dispensation of that fief. His own personal agent will rule on
> Arrakis.”

Comment: Hence also why the Baron sends a series of proxies to rule in his stead rather than running the place himself

Comment: Just what does Herbert mean in calling it “geriatric spice,” that old people take it while putting on their Depends? That it promotes longevity, or is this just some zensunni gobbledegook flair given to spice to get the mind racing?

Comment: @SillybutTrue - "*relating to old people, especially with regard to their health care*". It prolongs life

Comment: In other words, Fiefdom of Arrakis is a massive Albatross of an honour. On paper, House Atreides is receiving an enormous honour and responsibility as befits their high status in the Landsraad. In reality, they have been removed from their seat of power, placed off-balance and vulnerable in a way the Harkonnens never were, and they know it.

Comment: @Valorum I always found the name really confusing, I just associate "geriatric" with infirmity and old people, not just age (I know it doesn't technically mean that) and also the use of "melange" as it's actual name - a melange of what?

Comment: @Whelkaholism I’ve been in same boat. It’s not like all the old people clamor for it, and there’s probably more younger people on it than old in any case.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 - Correct. The only miscalculation on Atreides' part was the willingness of Baron Harkonnen to bankrupt his House, because - literally - money, not the actual military strength, was the deciding factor here.

Comment: @AcePL What surprises me is that the Emperor actually has the power to outright give Arrakis to the Atreides. As a distinction from simply giving them the contract to manage it. This seems like something that should be an extraordinary distinction from simply being the incumbent. "Here is the most important planet in the universe, it's yours to do with as you please, try not to break it!"

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 - Now this is incorrect. Arrakis is sole source of spice, supply of which must not stop. This supply was threatened by de facto war of rebellion on Arrakis (between Harkonnen and Fremen). Atreides were ordered to take over planet as a fief and end that war (even if no one really knew the extent of it), which came with CHOAM directorship (which means LOTS of money), due to Leto's status in Landsraad, which was [essentially] in political opposition to the Emperor. I think Emperor was more or less forced politically to give Arrakis to Atreides.

Comment: @AcePL Ahh, good catch, It's been a while since I last read the book and most of my perception is coloured by the films, which universally emphasise that the Emperor is the one machinating the scenario and that CHOAM/Landsraad have very little to do with the decisions. Still, It does seem strange to me that rather than being contracted like the Harkonnens were, the Atreides are being given the whole planet as their fief, replacing Caladan rather than in addition. I don't think we're ever shown any other house changing homeworld like this, let alone the most vital world in the Empire.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 - I suggest you redo your comment starting with "now this is incorrect..." as a standalone answer. It certainly expands on the answer you were replying to, but it gives it additional context. I'd give it a +1.

Comment: @Deacon - Valorum's answer is perfectly fine. It answers the OP in best way possible, I'm just - as you said - giving context to it. Had I rework it into an Answer, it would not be to the question asked, at least not entirely.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 - Leto is Emperor's cousin (real one, not just the honorary title House Major used with each other), has strong claim to the throne and has male heir (unlike Emperor). Leto is also leading Opposition in the Landsraad, so getting fief to Arrakis is major political victory, but also, since he's imperial bloodline, this signals to all Houses, as well to Guild and Bene Gesserit, that Shaddam takes problems on Arrakis seriously, by giving that responsibility to best person after himself. Also, he IS machinating himself a lot, don't sell yourself short. It's just it's more nuanced.

Comment: @Whelkaholism it's a melange of different chemicals/spices.  The implication is that this particular mixture is so important it's sort of "stolen" what used to be non-specific terms (melange and spice).  If someone says "the melange" in this universe, the default assumption is that they mean "the melange [of spices from Arrakis]".  

Sort of like how in some areas you can say you're going to "the lake" and everyone knows exactly what lake you're talking about

Comment: @AcePL Totally get all of that. I'm just surprised that anyone is onboard with giving actual ownership of Arrakis, not just temporary stewardship, to anyone! (In as far as fiefdom is a permanent ownership) An actual permanent fiefdom of Arrakis. Not just contracting on-behalf of CHOAM, but outright saying that House Atreides's new homeworld is Arrakis. (to the point of requiring them to give up Caladan). It's pretty extraordinary right? I'm not reading too much into it? The more I think about it, the weirder it seems. Changing homeworld isn't the norm for great houses AFAIK.

Comment: @Whelkaholism As noted by Dr. Yueh, it never tastes the same twice. Presumably, that's why it's called a melange, despite being a single spice, rather than a mixture.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 Nope, you're reading it right. Also, as you noted, a part of Emperor's machinations. Regardless of it being a trap, it was also an opportunity and a victory for Atreides politically. In addition to it being rare, it was also an order form the Emperor, to be either obeyed or go renegade. Very elegant solution to a problem that can't be solved in the open - Emperor wanted Leto Atreides gone, but couldn't do it himself. What better way to maneuver so outwardly it all looks legit, while helping third party with a grudge in getting rid of closest competition.